# Angular can't find module local file

Tags: angular

In my application, in various component I called SharedService

but ts error can't find module Sharedservice when

```
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared/shared.service';
```

even **Path Intellisense** is pointing properly

But, when I changed to relative

```
import { SharedService } from '../app/shared/shared.service';
```

Is there any place where it is need to be written to point to src/...

Comment: `"sourceRoot": "src",` should be by default in `angular.json`

Comment: It is likely that you need to go up one more level in your import like this `import { SharedService } from '../../app/shared/shared.service';`

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure you have the baseUrl properly set**

If you're using `paths` in your `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.app.json`, you need to also configure the `baseUrl` property in the same file.

Most commonly, this `baseUrl` property should be updated from `./` to `src`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure your tsconfig.json as follows,

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "components/*":  [ "app/components/*" ],
      "services/*":  [ "app/services/*" ],
      "shared/*":  [ "app/shared/*" ]
    },
```

You can do import as follows

```
import { SharedService } from 'shared/shared.service';
```

Comment: the old code is running without what you have mentioned & you have mentioned path from 'app'. If application is not recognizing src/ how it will recognize 'app', that to the directory where this file is there, there 'src' is there. I assume you are saing tsconfig.app.json. I will try & let you know

Comment: The `tsconfig.json` is up one level from `tsconfig.app.json` (In the root of your app if you built it using `ng`)